# How to get eclipse Tag List Programmatically using a plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am a noob to the Eclipse Plugin Development , and I am doing my 1st project.

I need to get the list of tag messages (`TODO`,`FIXME`, ... etc) in PRE_BUILD event.
I went through the `org.eclipse.ui.views.tasklist package`, but I wasn't able find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are `IMarker` objects, in particular markers with the type `IMarker.TASK` for TODO...

Markers belong to `IResource` objects (`IFile`, `IFolder`, ...)

You can use the `IResource`

```
public IMarker[] findMarkers(String type, boolean includeSubtypes, int depth)
```

method to find all markers on a resource.

So, for example, if you have an `IProject` you can use

```
IMarker[] markers = project.findMarkers(IMarker.TASK, true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE);
```

to get all the task markers for resources in the project.